# Cannot upgrade npm to the latest version on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

No matter what I've tried, I can't update npm to the latest version (currently `3.10.7`) on my Mac. The install seems to work, in terms of pulling down the latest version, but the latest version is stuck at 3.8.0. Here are all the details I can pull up.

system: `Mac OS X El Capitan, Version 10.11.6`

command: `node -v`
results: `v6.6.0`

command: `npm -v`
results: `3.8.0`

command: `npm cache clean`
results: *nothing*

command: `which npm`
results: `Users/wrburgess/.npm-packages/bin/npm`

command: `npm install -g npm@latest`
results:

`/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/local/lib
├── abbrev@1.0.9
├── aproba@1.0.4
├── fstream@1.0.10
├─┬ fstream-npm@1.1.1
│ └─┬ fstream-ignore@1.0.5
│   └── minimatch@3.0.3
├─┬ glob@7.0.5
│ └── minimatch@3.0.3
├── graceful-fs@4.1.5
├── has-unicode@2.0.1
├── lodash.clonedeep@4.4.1
├── lodash.union@4.5.0
├── lodash.uniq@4.4.0
├── lodash.without@4.3.0
├── minimatch@3.0.3
├─┬ node-gyp@3.4.0
│ └── minimatch@3.0.3
├─┬ npm@3.10.7
│ └─┬ init-package-json@1.9.4
│   └─┬ glob@6.0.4
│     └── minimatch@3.0.3
├── npm-package-arg@4.2.0
├── npm-user-validate@0.1.5
├── read-package-tree@5.1.5
├── readable-stream@2.1.4
├── request@2.74.0
├── rimraf@2.5.4
├── which@1.2.10
└── wrappy@1.0.2`

command: `npm cache clean`
results: *nothing*

command: `npm -v`
results: `3.8.0`

Any ideas?

Comment: did you exec `npm -v` in the same terminal?, try to close it and run it on another new terminal.

Comment: I did try a terminal restart without success

Comment: How did you originally install Node/NPM? The location of your `npm` executable (in `/Users/wrburgess/.npm-packages`) isn't standard (the official installer will install it as `/usr/local/bin/npm`).

Comment: I have no idea how it was installed before, but I recognize that the current executable isn't standard. I have no idea how to change it, though.

Comment: how did you get it to update, i am stuck at the same issue

Comment: @Baig I use nvm, now. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Thanks I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling it in order to update it

Answer (score 0):

When installing npm modules globally you need to use `sudo`(in OS X at least)

So use:

```
sudo npm install npm
```

If you look higher up in your terminal output you will se some error messages if you do not use `sudo`.

Comment: I just made `/usr/local` writable for myself to prevent having to use `sudo`.

Comment: if you want to do that you could just change the ownership of the directory http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192229

Comment: Well, yeah, that's how I made it writable for myself ;D

Comment: The majority of articles I've read online flatly state to avoid the use of sudo with npm.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add `/Users/wrburgess/.npm-packages/bin` after `/Users/wrburgess/.npm-packages` in your *PATH*.

So, you can put in your *~/.bash_profile*:

> export PATH=/Users/wrburgess/.npm-packages:/Users/wrburgess/.npm-packages/bin:~/.npm:$PATH